# Generate SQL rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

Given a number of types and a number of occurrences per type, I would like to generate something like this in T-SQL:

```
Occurrence | Type
-----------------
         0 | A
         1 | A
         0 | B
         1 | B
         2 | B
```

Both the number of types and the number of occurrences per type are presented as values in different tables.

While I can do this with WHILE loops, I'm looking for a better solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Please share you Other table also.

Comment: Have you tried something before asking your question?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) At the very least, post a data sample or (better) create a simple example in [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with a number-table which i would use.

```
SELECT Occurrence = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Type) - 1
     , Type
FROM Numbers num
INNER JOIN #temp1 t
ON num.n BETWEEN 1 AND t.Occurrence
```

Tested with this sample data:

```
create table #temp1(Type varchar(10),Occurrence int)
insert into  #temp1 VALUES('A',2)
insert into  #temp1 VALUES('B',3)
```

How to create a number-table? http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1

Comment: Thanks, that worked. One minor thing though - 
ON n BETWEEN 1 and t.Occurrence should be:
ON n.COLUMNAME BETWEEN 1 and T.Occurrence

Comment: @mo5470: : in my number-table `n` is the column-name. But you're right, that's a little bit confusing since the table alias was also `n`. I've channged that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a table with the columns `type` and `num`, you have two approaches.  One way is to use recursive CTEs:

```
with CTE as (
      select type, 0 as occurrence, num
      from table t
      union all
      select type, 1 + occurrence, num
      from cte
      where occurrence + 1 < num
     )
select cte.*
from cte;
```

You may have to set the `MAXRECURSION` option, if the number exceeds 100.

The other way is to join in a numbers table.  SQL Server uses `spt_values` for this purpose:

```
select s.number - 1 as occurrence, t.type
from table t join
     spt_values s
     on s.number <= t.num ;
```